# Clear markers on Google maps v3 store locator when new distance selected

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have seen answers for a similar query but I just can't get it working so I was hoping someone will see a problem with my code or be able to suggest how I can fix this

To briefly explain what i am doing - a user enters their postcode and selects from a dropdown the distance in miles that they want to see stores from their postcode.  Using ajax in mvc I am returning a list of stores with markers on the Google map.

When a user makes a new selection the markers are not clearing.  I have seen that I need to put the markers in an array and then clear them but not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here are the pieces of code that i have used:

At the top of the script:

```
            var map;
            var markers = [];



            // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
           function clearMarkers(){
              for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++){
                markers[i].set_map(null);
              }
              markers.length = 0;
            };
```

when the dropdown list is clicked:

```
 $("#distanceMiles").change(function () {

                     clearMarkers();
```

within the ajax success:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.StoreLat, item.StoreLong),
                                            icon: iconurl,
                                            map: map
                                        });
                                        marker.setMap(map);
```

And here is the script all together:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
               //<![CDATA[
               //if the postcode input field is clicked on the dropdown should clear

                            $("#enterPostCode").click(function() {
                                $("#distanceMiles").find('option:first').attr('selected','selected');

                            });

           $("#hiddenPostMsg ").hide();

            $(".divAddress").hide();
            //indicates whether your application is using a sensor, such as a GPS device to determine user's location - we are not
            //  google.load("maps", "2", { "other_params": "sensor=false" });
            //Starts a javascript function named initialize which sets the Google Map display parameters, and is called in the html body upon page load
            var map;
            var markers = [];



            // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
           function clearMarkers(){
              for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++){
                markers[i].set_map(null);
              }
              markers.length = 0;
            }; 



            function initialize() {

                var zoomGrade = 10;

                var mapProp = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.694031, 0.04505),
                    zoom: zoomGrade,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), mapProp);




                $("#distanceMiles").change(function () {

                     clearMarkers();

                    $(".divAddress").hide();
                    $(".addressscroll ul").html('');
                    //clear the old markers if there are any
                   // gmap.clearOverlays();

                    $("#distanceMiles option:selected").each(function () {

                        var manufacturerId =  <%= Model.Manufacturer.Id%>;

                        var postcodeEntered = $("#enterPostCode").val();

                        var milesEntered = $(this).val();

                        if (postcodeEntered != "" && milesEntered != "") {

                         $("#hiddenPostMsg ").hide();

                            var theUrl = "/Widgets/GetPostcodes/" + manufacturerId + "/" + postcodeEntered + "/" + milesEntered;
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                url: theUrl,
                                data: { 'manufacturerId': manufacturerId, 'postcodeEntered': postcodeEntered, 'milesEntered': milesEntered },
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (data) {

                                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {



                                        var item = data[i];



                                        //the count goes next to the retailer so we know which marker is for which
                                        var count = i + 1;

                                        //to custom the markers i need to use the number we are on (i)
                                        var iconurl = "https://where-to-buy.co/content/images/marker" + count + ".png";

                                        //Sets the initial map location (latitude, longitude) in decimal degree format, and the zoom level (1 is zoomed out - 21 is farthest zoom in)
                                        map.setZoom(item.ZoomLevel);
                                        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(item.OriginalLat, item.OriginalLong));


                                        //Close bracket to end the function named initialize !!!very important to not delete this!!!
                                        //javascript that sets up variables that enable the map to draw a custom icon.
                                       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.StoreLat, item.StoreLong),
                                            icon: iconurl,
                                            map: map
                                        });
                                        marker.setMap(map);

                                        //End of add marker code
                                        var showDistance = item.Distance.toFixed(2);
                                        //now i need to create a list that will display on the right hand side inside .addressscroll
                                        $(".addressscroll ul").append("<li class =\"storeLi\"><div class=singleadddress><p class=\"storeNameP\">" + count + " " + item.StoreName + "</p><p class=\"storeP\">" + item.Address1 + "<br/>" + item.TownCity + " " + item.Postcode + "<br/>" + item.Telephone + "<br/>" + showDistance + " miles</p><p class =\"linksP\" ><a class =\"storeA\" href = \"https://www.google.com/maps?q=" + item.MapsPostcode + "\" target=\"_blank\" >Display Map</a></p><p class =\"linksP\"><a class =\"storeA\" href = \"https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=d&hl=en&geocode=&saddr=" + item.OriginalMapsPostcode + "&daddr=" + item.MapsPostcode + "\" target=\"_blank\" >Display Route</a></p></div></li> ");

                                        //Creates a directions object and registers a map and DIV to hold the resulting computed directions
                                        //                                                var directionsPanel;
                                        //                                                var directions;
                                        //                                                directionsPanel = document.getElementById("my_directions_div");
                                        //                                                directions = new GDirections(gmap, directionsPanel);
                                        //                                                //Specify the FROM and TO for your directions: postcode to postcode
                                        //                                                directions.load("from: "+ item.OriginalPostcode +", to: "+ item.Postcode + "");


                                    }

                                    $(".divAddress").show();


                                    $(".upHide").hide();
                                    // get the number of .child elements
                                    var totalitems = $(".addressscroll .storeLi").length;
                                  if(totalitems >= 2) {
                                       $(".downHide").show();
                                  }
                                    // get the height of .w6392597
                                    var scrollval = $('.storeLi').height();
                                    // work out the total height.
                                    var totalheight = (totalitems * scrollval) - ($(".addressscroll").height());
                                    $(document).on("click", ".downHide", function () {
                                        var currentscrollval = $('.addressscroll').scrollTop();

                                        $('.addressscroll').scrollTop(scrollval + currentscrollval);

                                        // hide/show buttons
                                        if (currentscrollval == totalheight) {
                                            $(this).hide();
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            $(".upHide").show();

                                        }
                                    }); $(document).on("click", ".upHide", function () {
                                        var currentscrollval = parseInt($('.addressscroll').scrollTop());

                                        $('.addressscroll').scrollTop(currentscrollval - scrollval);

                                        // hide/show buttons
                                        if ((scrollval + currentscrollval) == scrollval) {
                                            $(this).hide();
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            $(".downHide").show();
                                        }
                                    });


                                    if(totalitems == 0) {
                                        $(".downHide").hide();
                                        $("#hiddenPostMsg ").show();
                                        $("#hiddenPostMsg ").text("Invalid Postcode. Please try again");

                                    }

                                }

                            });

                        }
                        else if (postcodeEntered == "") {

                            //here i want to clear the dropdown aswel
                             $("#hiddenPostMsg ").show();
                            $("#distanceMiles").find('option:first').attr('selected','selected');

                        }


                    });

                });


            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
               google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                        </script>
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not putting the markers in the array when you create them.

```
 //javascript that sets up variables that enable the map to draw a custom icon.
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.StoreLat, item.StoreLong),
   icon: iconurl,
   map: map
 });
 marker.setMap(map);
 markers.push(marker);
```

Not sure if this is a problem, but you have inconsistent use of setMap:

```
markers[i].set_map(null);

marker.setMap(map);
```

Comment: lifesaver!! thankyou and i did change the setmap so that it was consistent! thanks so much